# Есть ли похожее выражение (a==1 && a==2 && a==3) чтобы как в JS вернуло TRUE?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Такое выражение `(a==1 && a==2 && a==3)` в JavaScript, как было [показано здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270127/can-a-1-a-2-a-3-ever-evaluate-to-true/48270314#48270314), может вернуть `TRUE`.

Просто интересно, а есть ли также способ в PL/SQL, чтобы похожее выражение вернуло `TRUE`?

<sub>Свободный перевод [(a== 1 && a ==2 && a==3) ever evaluate to true in pl sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49354890) от участника [@Miracle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9191797/miracle)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/49354890

Answer (score 3):

Только интереса ради:

```sql
SQL> create package p as n int := 0; end;
  2  /

SQL> create function a return int is begin p.n:=p.n+1; return p.n; end;
  2  /

SQL> set autoprint on
SQL> var res varchar2 (8)
SQL> exec if (a = 1 and a = 2 and a = 3) then :res:='TRUE'; end if;

RES
--------------------------------
TRUE
```

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49355405) от участника [@Connor McDonald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7367293/connor-mcdonald)</sub>